# PHP socket_recv not getting all bits of byte

Tags: php, string, sockets, bit, sign

I have an application where I am receiving data using socket_recv. The data received ranges from hex 07 to ff which is stored in string. the problem is I am getting data like hex 3f(00111111) when I should receive ff(11111111).
below is the example code.

```
if(socket_recv ( $sock , $str , 6 , MSG_DONTWAIT ) === FALSE)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
```

Please suggest if there is a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Why would it be a problem with socket? You are apparently receiving something. The code posted doesn't suggest why you *think* the data received is wrong. This isn't a problem related to sockets, and without entire code + input data it's hard to tell you how to solve the problem. As your question is currently, it appears there's no problem with code whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I have also come to same conclusion. I will remove question once conformed. currently I don't have sender code.